# Counting dates on Android

Tags: android, calendar, days

Well i'm currently building an app for android and i need to store a day and count how many days until that day comes.

I store the day on shared prefs. First i initialize the calendars.

```
         Calendar next = Calendar.getInstance();
         Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then i set the "next" calendar

```
            nday = prefs.getInt("d", 0);
            nmonth = prefs.getInt("m",0);
            nyear = prefs.getInt("y",0);
            next.set(nyear, nmonth, nday);
```

Then i do this to calculate how many days left.

```
            diff =next.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTimeInMillis();
            diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
            output.setText(diffDays + " Days left");
```

And here is the problem. The calculator was working great until 2 days ago. When it supposed to say "3 days" it was writing "2 days" and it still goes one day wrong. If i try close and open the app, sometimes it calculates the days correct and sometimes it misses one day... Can someone understands whats wrong? I have diff and diffDays as long. I tried cast them as int but i still got the same problem, sometimes it writes 3 days left, sometimes 2....

---

ok i found out how to solve this. It seems that the getInstance have difference in milliseconds so i did this

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,00); 
    now.set(Calendar.MINUTE ,00);
    now.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
    now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,00);
```

get the day from shared prefs

```
       nday = extras.getInt("nDay");
       nmonth = extras.getInt("nMonth");
       nyear = extras.getInt("nYear");
       //set the calendar
       next.set(nyear, nmonth, nday, 00, 00,00);
       next.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,00);
```

and finally calculate the difference

```
    long diff = 0;
    diff = next.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTimeInMillis();
    diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    output.setText(diffDays + " Days");
```

now i get the real difference without any mistakes, thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: When you're creating your dates are you cleaning them so that they properly reference to midnight and not the hours and minutes you create them?

Comment: i use Calendar.getInstance()
how can i clean them??

Comment: Clean them by setting the MINUTES, SECONDS and MILLISECONDS fields to 0.

Comment: if the problem is solved, you should accept the relevant answer or post your solution, don't edit solved into the title.

Comment: i have posted it under my original post. There is a line and then
i write "ok i found out how to solve this..." and then post my solution. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also use the calendar for calculating dates.

```
Calendar diff = Calendar.getInstance();
long diffMillis = next.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTimeInMillis();
diff.setTimeInMilliSeconds(Math.abs(diffMillis));
int days = diff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

if (diffMillis < 0L) {
  days *= -1;
}
```

Comment: thats a good idea but i cant use it because if next day passes i want to show -1, -2 etc... if i try with your way instead of -1 it shows 365. Nice idea though

Comment: You can solve this by using the absolute value of milliseconds and sign it after the calculation. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is implicitly casting to long, so you are losing some of your minutes and hours.

Declare `diffDays` as double, then you can show to the user when there are, for example `2.5 days` and it won't show it as `2 days`. Or, you could take the integer part for the days, and calculate the hour from the fraction:

```
int hour = (diffDays - Math.floor(diffDays))*24
```

This gives you the minute. Just make sure you did declare `diffDays` as double or float.

Comment: I tried it but now it writes "1.0 days" and still is wrong, sometimes when i close and open it it writes "2.0 days".. How can this happen? Sometimes it calculates 2 days and sometimes 3... maybe if i declare the dates like this next -> "2-11-2011 00:00"  now -> "31-10-2011 00:00" maybe then i can get the correct difference

Comment: But if you declare them this way, you lose the hours... If you don't care about them, you can do it.

Comment: yea i dont want the hours i just want the difference in days between two dates.

Comment: So you can do what you suggested in your first comment.